# What is causing this odd routing problem in CI4

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am coming to the line of thinking that I am missing something very simple here, but just cannot see it, despite having been coding with PHP and CI since CI2. I have been pondering this for nearly 48 hours.

ON both my local MAMP environment on the Mac, and on a shared hosting platform, the following routing code is misbehaving.  Allow_rewrite is switched on, and the .htaccess file is working.  The code was developed initially with the alpha version of CI4, and now updated through Composer to CI4.0.4.

In /config/routes.php I have:

```
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(true); //This has been tried true and false
 
/**
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Route Definitions
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->get('/dashboard', 'Users::dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard']);
```

That works fine, and routes to the dashboard, with no index.php file in evidence and all is ok.

However, once the route definitions change to:

```
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->get('/dashboard/news/(:num)', 'Users::newsstory/$1');
$routes->get('/dashboard/account', 'Users::accountsettings');
$routes->get('/dashboard', 'Users::dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard']);
```

Then the /dashboard route still works, but when you navigate to /dashboard/account - it says cannot find Users::account.  When you navigate to /dashboard/news/11 is says cannot find Home::index.

Anything beyond the first level routing is mis-routing.  Within the users controller are functions called dashboard, account settings and newsstory($storyid) but the latter two are never called.  I can get the segment data by breaking down the URL in the code, but that does not solve the issue of routing.

change the dashboard entries to be grouped:

```
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->group('/dashboard', function($routes)
{
  $routes->get('/news/(:num)', 'Users::newsstory/$1');
  $routes->get('/account', 'Users::accountsettings');
  $routes->get('/', 'Users::dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard']);
});
```

The same thing happens. /dashboard/ routes fine, the other two create file not found errors, looking for \App\Controllers\Dashboard::account in the case of /dashboard/account.

Where am I going wrong - can anyone tell me?  The whole development work is stuck till I can sort this out!

Rich

Comment: isn't the route pointing to an account setting missing some kind of account id? so the route could look like `$routes->get('/dashboard/account/(:any)', 'Users::accountsettings/$1');`. But without seeing your function accountsettings($id) it's difficult to say...

Comment: No, it doesn't matter what it is.  You could do $routes->get('/dashboard/account', 'Users::account'); and it still fails.  The problem occurs anytime there is two or more segments.  If its just one segment e.g. $routes->get('/dashboard', 'Users::account'); it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.  Unfortunately, I do not know the exact answer, but it must have been a carry over somewhere from one of the pre-release versions.  I started coding this site with 4.0.0-alpha, and have updated the base code with every release.

However, I have created a fresh CI4.0.4 project, and moved all of my code into it, updated the config to reflect what I had previously, and everything now works as it should.  That proves my code was ok, and it must just have been a bug that in the framework code somewhere.

All has now been committed to the GIT repo and works find on the end server as well.